# MySQL query to check mutual values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL DB that resembles the following:

```
    uid          suid
    1              5
    1              6
    2              5
    5              1
    5              2
```

I am giving it a single unique "uid" via the POST method, call it 1. What I need to do is return all "suid"  where $uid "has" suid  AND suid (as uid) "has" $uid (as suid.) So, in the above example, the script should only return 5.

I know my first step is

```
    "Select * FROM table Where uid = $uid"
```

then maybe I have to loop through the results and query the DB WHERE suid = $uid.
I do not know how to do the second query. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

One option here would be to self join, with the join condition being that `uid` in one table matches `suid` in the other table, and vice-versa for the `suid` in the first table.

```
SELECT
    t1.suid
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.uid  = t2.suid AND
       t1.suid = t2.uid
WHERE
    t1.uid = 1
```

Before applying the `WHERE` clause, the above query would return two records:

```
uid | suid  (uid not selected)
1   | 5
5   | 1
```

The `WHERE` clause then chooses the first record, which is what we want, using the `uid` parameter which you pass it.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: ok. say I defined this as $my_query. Can I use $result = $conn->query($my_query); While($row = $result->fetch_assoc())

Comment: Your question is vague, and I'm not a PHP person.  If you have a serious hurdle with your PHP you might also want to ask another question.  The query I gave you is valid and will run on MySQL.

Comment: Ok. I will give it a shot and see what I get.

Answer (score 1):

this is what I came up with:

```
    $uid = $_POST["UID"];

    $myquery = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE uid = '$uid'";

    $result = $conn->query($myquery);
     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $myquery2 = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE uid = '" . $row['suid'] . "' AND suid = '$uid'"; 
        $result2 =  $conn->query($myquery2);   

        if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {

            while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

                    echo $row["uid"].
              "!@#$";

        }
        }       
    }
}

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

I feel it is not pretty but it did the trick.